# Developing the state space model of an electrical circuit with 4 loops

Tags: state-space

I am trying to get the state space model for the given electrical circuit, but I am confused about selecting the state variable. How do I write the equation for the state space model?

[image: schematic]

Comment: gbk0029 - Hi, This looks like a development of [your earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/636777/help-required-regarding-kvl-and-kcl-laws-to-develop-the-state-model) on the same topic (overlapping?). Having two open questions on the same topic is a bad plan here, as it could waste the time of readers who spend time on a question which is now obsolete. Please review these two questions and either close one, or if they are somehow both needed and don't overlap, please edit them both to link to the other one & explain in each exactly why they are both needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is define inputs and outputs of the circuit (voltage or current). Then you need to define what states you need to monitor.

This whole circuit could be reduced to a transfer function and then converted to state space.

Comment: The input is the voltage source and output will be voltage across capacitor C4 i.e across 500uF. Could you convert it to state space?